# Triggering button press from raspberry pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, hacking

I want to be able to solder to a gamecube controller circuit board and, from the raspberry pi, trigger the button press to register. From what I understand, the buttons work by being grounded when the conductive pad is pressed down. My current thought is to hold the button at the input voltage then, using the pi, when I want the button "pressed" use GPIO.low to do a weak ground and hopefully make the button register as pressed. Anyone know if this will work? I am a beginner at this stuff and have very little experience or knowledge on electric work.

Comment: "From what I understand, the buttons work by being grounded when the conductive pad is pressed down." That *can* be the case, but button matrices are often *not* wired like that. Are you *sure* that's the case?

Comment: Ive tried touching a jumper cable from the ground pin on the pi to the exposed circuitry for the button and it registers. Havent tried any more testing though

Answer (score 1):

That sounds likely to work. the ground produced by a low raspberry pi output is probably much stronger than is needed by the controller.

but check that the high voltage of the controller input is no more than the 3.6V maximum of the raspberry pi GPIO.